# Angucomplete-alt to return an Array of results

Tags: arrays, angularjs, search, web

In my 'search.html' template I use this to create an auto complete input that searches a DB.

```
<angucomplete-alt id="mainSearch" 
input-changed="track "
input-class="form-control search-widget"
pause="400" 
placeholder="Enter URL" 
remote-url="/api/businesses/?q=" 
selected-object="searchObj"
title-field="url"/>
```

and In my controller my 'track' function gets called every time the input in the field changes, how do I get it to log an array of the results it finds, the same array that it uses to populate the list of matches?

```
$scope.track = function(){
  console.log($scope.results);
}
```

Comment: where is the element `angucomplete-alt` coming from?

Comment: this plugin https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt

Answer (score 0):

looking into the docs, I see in the function inputChangeHandler, the folloing code:

```
if (scope.inputChanged) {
      str = scope.inputChanged(str);
    }
```

so, I guess, you don't get into your function only the string, = the input of the user, not the results. (which I guess is only available in the isolated scope).